# Someone know this "language"?

Tags: php, parsing

I need to parse this language in PHP, but I don't know what language it is and how to parse it.

**Does someone know what language it is?**

And if it's not a language, can someone explain me how to parse it?

Thank you very much

```
include "folder/file1.conf"
include "folder/file2.conf"

auth-mocked {
  welcome = "Welcome"
  login = "Login to continue:"
  placeholder = "login"
  button = "Login"
  error = "Error:"
}

auth {
  sso {
    validation {
      expected-uuid = "You need an UID"
    }
    session-not-found = "session was not found"
  }
}

header {
  company-name = "Company name"

  help-popup {
    title = "Need help?"
    paragraph = "If you have any issue, you can contact your dedicated interlocutor:"
  }

  language-popup {
    title = "Change language"
  }

  language = "Change language"
  profile = "My profile"
  terms-of-use = "Terms of use"
  ao-documents = "Documents"
  logout = "Logout"
  user = "User"
}

black-panel {
  common {
    form = "You are currently filling the form:"
    btn-i-understand = "Ok, thanks"
    btn-link-view = "View"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a translation file to me, it tells you where to place which text elements. This is not a "program", it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes it's translation files, but I need to parse them in PHP, first I thought it was JSON

Comment: So it's the format of the file that's the problem, not the language. It's very simple, so it's easy to build a parser for it in PHP.

Comment: Google "recursive descent parser php"

Comment: Probably, the format is ".conf", but I don't know how to build a parser in PHP
Barmar, ok I will try thanks

Comment: @Kodmit If you don't know how to build a parser, then what difference does it make what language it is?

Comment: @Barmar because If I know the name maybe I will find a librairy to parse it and so I don't have to code a parser by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finaly created my own parser to get the label for each keys.

```
function parseFile($file){
$title = "";
$key = "";
$value = "";
$str = "";
$array = array();
$results = array();
$lines = file('./generated_json/'.$file);

foreach($lines as $line){
    if(strpos($line, " {\n")){
        $title = str_replace(" {", "", $line);
        array_push($array, $title);
        $str = implode(".", $array);
    }

    if(strpos($line, "=")){
        $keyEx = explode("=", $line);
        $key = $keyEx[0];
        $value = $keyEx[1];
        $parsed = $str.".".$key;
        $parsed = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $parsed);
        $parsed = str_replace("=", "", $parsed);
        array_push($results, $parsed." = ".$value);
    }   

    if(strpos($line, "}\n")){
        array_pop($array);
        $str = implode(".", $array);
    }   

}
return $results;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

It may be an homemade file format, but here is a list of common file formats used for translation : 
http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/formats/

If you don't find your file format in there, you could probably write a parser for it.

Comment: I don't find it, so I need to learn how to build a parser in php ^^"